# Quick way to repeatedly filter a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, plyr

I have a data frame that consists of a series of 100K+ observations, each of which has a POSIXt timestamp. The observations are in date/time order. The time intervals between the observations varies. I need to create a new vector in the data frame with a value for each observation that is the number of observations, within the 5 minutes after that observation, meeting some criteria (in the example below, the goal vector needs to have a value of TRUE. In the actual problem, the criteria are more complex and depend on values for a number of vectors in the data frame).

At the moment, performance is dreadful for the example below:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(1)
observations = 1000
startTime = Sys.time()

data <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = observations))
colnames(data) <- c("timeStamp", "goal", "derived")
data$goal <- (runif(observations,0,1.1) > 1.0)
data$timeStamp <- runif(observations,1,90*60) + startTime
data <- arrange(data, timeStamp)
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  data[i,"derived"] <- filter(data, goal == TRUE, timeStamp > data[[i,"timeStamp"]], timeStamp < (data[[i,"timeStamp"]] + (5 * 60))) %>% nrow
}
summary(data)
```

Could the data filtering operation be performed without creating a new data frame within the loop?

Is there a better way to optimise the process?

Ideally, is there a way to eliminate looping over the rows of the data frame?

Comment: You may wish to add a set.seed(123) before the data creation so it always give the same dataset (this should allow to validate answers more easily)

Comment: I think the rolling join in data.table package may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(dat), timeStamp)
dat[, derived := dat[.(goal = TRUE, ts1 = timeStamp, ts2 = timeStamp + 5 * 60), 
    on = .(goal, timeStamp >= ts1, timeStamp <= ts2), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]
dat
```

> ```
>                 timeStamp  goal derived
>    1: 2017-11-24 07:19:47  TRUE       3
>    2: 2017-11-24 07:19:48 FALSE       2
>    3: 2017-11-24 07:19:51 FALSE       2
>    4: 2017-11-24 07:20:04 FALSE       2
>    5: 2017-11-24 07:20:06 FALSE       2
>   ---                                  
>  996: 2017-11-24 08:49:06  TRUE       2
>  997: 2017-11-24 08:49:13 FALSE       1
>  998: 2017-11-24 08:49:16  TRUE       1
>  999: 2017-11-24 08:49:25 FALSE       0
> 1000: 2017-11-24 08:49:40 FALSE       0
> ```

#### Reproducible data

```
observations <- 1000
startTime <- as.POSIXct("2017-11-24 07:19:44")
set.seed(123L)
dat <- data.frame(
  timeStamp = runif(observations, 1, 90*60) + startTime,
  goal = runif(observations, 0, 1.1) > 1.0
)
```

Comment: [The data table documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) is helpful in understanding this solution.